# Relating two classes and displaying in one query using parse.com on android

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation

I have two classes one is the User class and the other is NewsFeed. I need to join both the classes so that i can get the title present in the NewsFeed and the name present in User class.

I tried this but it fails

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Feed");
    query.whereEqualTo("AuthorId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> relationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    relationQuery.whereMatchesQuery("ObjectId",query);
    relationQuery.find();
```

This always returns null if i remove the relation query i get all the data based on authorid.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to query the feed, as you already have the user object (currentUser). Get the name from the currentUser object.

You are getting null since you are trying to match the Objectid with the result of the first query, which would be a list of one feed object.

Comment: what if i want to load other columns in the User class or join other class

Comment: Like any other object: ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("name");

Comment: How can we get the objectId from the query so that i can add them to relation because ParseRelation<ParseObject> requires to be a ParseObject and when i try to use getObjectId() it returns as a string

Comment: The objectId IS a String. If you want to relate two objects, you add the actual object to the ParseRelation. So, if you want to add a user to the relation with Feed, you create a field on Feed called "author" or "user" or whatever you think appropriate, and then you add the actual user object to the relation:  feed.put("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); - assuming that "feed" is the Feed object.

Comment: As a side note; you seldom need to define such a relation as a ParseRelation. A Pointer will cover your needs in most cases.

Comment: One last doubt what if i want to add other users object based on query result, here ParseUser.getCurrenUser() wont work. This is where i am stuck

Comment: If you want to add another user, you query for the user, get the user from the List you get in return and then add that user object with feed.put("author", otherUser); How are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
1)

1. Replace your second line   `query.whereEqualTo("AuthorId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId().toString());`

with this

```
query.whereEqualTo("AuthorId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

2. And to get the comments for a post : Put a POINTER type field in COMMENTS class which points to the POST. Then remove the third line in the code you posted, replace it with `query.whereEqualTo("field_pointerTopost",post_object_id);`

Comment: 1. This will only work if the AuthorId is a pointer. 2. Comments? The OP doesn't mention comments at all. And not POST either...